# What is the angle of a space diagonal in a cuboid?

Tags: geometry

What is the angle ($\sigma$) from $D$ to $R$, expressed as function of $R$, $T$ and $H$?

[image: Cuboid]

Comment: Could you explain what ideas you've already had about the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was difficulter ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\tan \sigma= \frac{B}{R} =  \frac{\sqrt{T^2+H^2}}{R}$$

Comment: ...assuming "line of sight" is perpendicular to "B", for example: if "line of sight" is perpendicular to the plane "vertical-horizontal".

Comment: @Timbuc - it would seem that is the case, otherwise it wouldn't be a cuboid.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have difficulty seeing B is perpendicular to R, which in fact it is also perpendicular to any line through intersection of H-V.

$ \tan \sigma= \frac{B}{R} $

So, I marked out all right angles on your sketch.
[image: MwMYu.png]